# disable gps in nativescript

Tags: android, typescript, gps, nativescript

I am a native-script beginer and i am trying (with a switch ) to enable/disable the gps .
 i used native-geolocation plugin , and i use enableLocationRequest() : it works for enabling the gps , but **does not** for **disabling** .
Thanks for your help.
here is a part of my function :

```
dialogs.confirm({
        title: self.gpsEnable.get("status")? "Désactivation de Votre GPS" : "Activation de Votre GPS",
        message: self.gpsEnable.get("status")? "Voulez-vous désactiver votre gps ?": "Voulez-vous activer votre gps ?",
        okButtonText: self.gpsEnable.get("status")?"Désactiver" :"Activer",
        cancelButtonText: "Non Merci"
    }).then(function (result) {
        console.log("Dialog result: " + result);
        if(result){
            console.log("____result === "+result);
            geolocation.enableLocationRequest().then(self.setGPSSetting());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Disabling GPS is a bad idea.  If another app like Google Maps is using the GPS your app should not be able to turn it off.  enableLocationRequest just ensures that you have access to use GPS, I don't think it turns it on / off.

Comment: Thank you MR Johnson for your comment , in my case i need only a way (shortcut) to the android/ios interface wich enable disable gps (the user will have all the control) , with enableLocationRequest it works in case that the gps is in disabled state , so how can i do the same if the state is enabled?